# PHP escape error @ for production

Tags: php, escaping, fsockopen

I want to escape the error generated by `fsockopen` and it works like this.

```
if ($fp = @fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)) { //... }
```

but i have been trying other things to avoid `@` and I have not managed.

Is there a code that I can use that is equivalent to this?

I have tried as well something like this just for testing purposes:

```
try{
if ($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)) {
  /...
}
//..
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'Error';
}
```

It does not work.
`Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to localhost:79 (A connection
 attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established
 connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Comment: how about `error_reporting(0)`

Comment: You could set up a [custom error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: Guys, can you explain why is my question a bad question? Other wise, I will never learn. 
@user3113490  I might want to know what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) an convert all the errors to an exception you can catch afterwards:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext) {
    if(0 === error_reporting())
        return false;

    throw new PHPException($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext);
});
```

So now you can catch the PHP error:

```
try {
    if ($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)) {
      //...
    }
    //..
} catch (\Exception $e){
    echo 'Connection failed: ' , $e->getMessage();
}

echo 'Don\'t worry... go on!';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can disable notices and warnings in production systems (instead write to a log):

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

In development environments you'd probably want all errors, notices and warnings on though:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

check out the error reporting levels here: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

EDIT: To check for an error:

```
$fp = @fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
  echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
  ...
}
```

I think if you are handling failure scenarios then consciously suppressing a warning using @ is ok.